# How do I cite ebooks without page numbers?

Tags: citations, bibtex

I am directly quoting a sentence from an ebook. Thus, I want to add the page numbering to its citation. However, different to the print version, which I do not have, this ebook (Amazon Kindle version) does not have page numberings but rather "positions".

Do I just pretend it's a page numbering and note in the bibliography that it is a Kindle version? Or is there another way?

In case this is of interest, I am using Latex with Bibtex.

Comment: I just want to add that I sympathize with your question. It bugs me that a lot of online books and other online resources don't provide any guidelines for how to cite specific information in them. Therefore I always try to obtain a printed version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not providing page numbers with citations for their own sake, but to help readers to locate the cited passage, e.g., if they want to verify it or see it in context. (Therefore page numbers are already diminished in their usefulness for regular books as soon as there are two editions with significantly different paging.)

The arguably easiest way to locate a verbatim quote in an e-book is to just feed a few words into a full-text search. Thus giving page numbers or similar information has no purpose anymore. However, you could ease finding the location of the quote in a classical book by giving edition-independent location information, such as chapter and section numbers.

Note that this is a “utilitaristic” approach to citations. A relevant reader of your publication (e.g., a supervisor or reviewer) might have a “dogmatic” view on such things and thus require page numbers or similar for their own sake.

Comment: This is why you always include the edition in citing a paper book, if it is >1. Chapter and section numbers will often also not be edition-independent. And unless you cite something verbatim, a full text search will not necessarily find the spot in an ebook that your citation refers to.

Comment: 1) Sure, but the usefulness of page numbers is still diminished (and I claimed nothing more) as even libraries often do not have all editions of a book available. 2) True, but if the target of a non-verbatim cite is so small that chapter numbers etc. do not provide sufficiently accurate location information, neither would page numbers or similar, at least in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Since your quote is direct, I would not bother myself so much about it. Just cite the book and give a note that it's an `e-book`. You can add a chapter or section number if it exists. Anyways, it's a direct quote: people should trust you that it is there. And if they needed, then can use full-text search if they needed.

**However, it is necessary to provide as precise version information of the file as possible!**

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, in this case, it may be a good idea to cite your reference regarding the section and part from which you are directly quoting a sentence. I mean, you may cite the ebook the same as you used to do before, but, when you want the reader to be informed about the exact part in which your quotation exists; you may refer to the section and part instead of page numbers which do not exist. Another good idea may be mentioning the phrase: "PDF file position: Page ???" in the same place of citation in which the page number is mentioned and the reader will easily find the part of the reference.